# Crash when trying to Present View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am experiencing a crash on my app when the following code is executed:

```
- (void)presentSearchViewController
{
    if(!_searchController)
    {
        SearchStickerViewController *searchController = [[SearchStickerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SearchStickerViewController" bundle:nil];
        searchController.delegate = self;
        [searchController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        _searchController = searchController;
    }

    [self addChildViewController:_searchController];        
    [self.view addSubview:_searchController.view];
    [_searchController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

The strange thing is that I am using the same code to push other ViewControllers I have and it works just fine. It doesn't crash always, it starts crashing after I go back and forth for around the 5th time (maybe it crashes on the 6th or 7th).

The error I get is:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'child view
>   controller:< UICompatibilityInputViewController: 0x1004e6af0> should
>   have parent view controller:< CKFullScreenAppViewController:
>   0x104e458f0> but actual parent is < UIInputWindowController:
>   0x100830200>

The code I am using to dismiss the ViewController is:

```
- (void)dismissSearchResultsViewController
{
    [_searchController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [_searchController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [_searchController removeFromParentViewController];
}
```

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot/fix this?

Comment: Where's your call to dismiss the view controller?  Since you're affecting the parent when adding the child, you'll need to apply the inverse when you remove the child.

Comment: @fullofsquirrels I've edited the questions and added the code. txs

Comment: What's the difference between the `_searchResultsController` and `_searchController` ivars?

Comment: @fullofsquirrels sorry, copied the wrong dismiss code, now it's Ok. (they are both basically the same ivars)

Comment: k, got it.  Maybe try setting `_searchController` to `nil` on dismissal?  If you don't, then when you call `presentSearchViewController` the *next* time, it will result in your adding the now-defunct controller back into your view hierarchy instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Have you made any progress on this?

Comment: @fullofsquirrels not really, still kind of stuck. I was able to make crash less, but still happening. This is not an app but actually an App iMessage Extension

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing, also in an iMessage extension.

Comment: In my case this **might** be because I was calling `becomeFirstResponder` on a text field at the same time as I was requesting the expanded presentation style. When I stopped doing that, the crash went away. I'm not completely certain the two are linked though. Since you mention a search controller, it might be that you're doing the same thing.